# How do I get my message I send using MVVM Light IMessenger between 2 VMs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have 2 ViewModels and both use the ViewModelBase Interface from MVVM Light

I have one view (Which is a tab created in the other view in question) which handles login and saves that in this member

```
private int loginRights;
```

I then want that var to be sent recieved in the other view so it can create tabs depending on the userRights level. (This is not a serius app, but merely a project for learning to use MVVM so security is NOT an issue)
So I have this to send it

```
loginRights = -1;
MessengerInstance.Send(loginRights);
```

But then I am in doubt what I am supposed to write in the recieving ViewModel, also is it possible to get the recieving class to execute something as soon as the sending ViewModels sends new data?

I have this

```
MessengerInstance.Register<int>(this, success);
private void success(int rights)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rights);
}
```

But that aint working at all, but its pretty hard to find some decent guides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this isn't working for you, but using `int` as the message type is a *very bad* idea... What if you need to send an `int` value that has a completely different meaning, unrelated to login rights? All ViewModels that registered for `int` will receive it too, and they won't know what it means.

You should create specific classes for your messages, so that each kind of message is clearly identifiable.

---

EDIT: I had a look at your code, apparently you're creating the messenger instance explicitly in the constructor. If you do the same in the other ViewModel, they will use different messenger instances, so they won't be able to exchange messages. **You have to use the same messenger instance in both ViewModels**. Instead of creating a messenger instance explicitly, try using `Messenger.Default`, and it should work fine.

Comment: Ok changed that plus I have changed some other things, but here are my 2 classes http://pastebin.com/Xsvmxqxd http://pastebin.com/53zai2qm but nothing is outputtet when I click he button

Comment: @Mech0z, yes, static members are shared across the whole app domain

Answer (score 0):

i dont know mvvm-light messenger, but i suggest that do you register after you send your message.

the scenario should work if you have the login instance and the other vm instance and if you the first register and second send the message.

maybe you can give some more infos.

EDIT:
see Thomas Levesque answer, you have to use the same instance of the messenger of course. Singleton or somenthing else.

Comment: my 2 classes http://pastebin.com/Xsvmxqxd http://pastebin.com/53zai2qm but nothing is outputtet when I click he button